# How to make a group id using pandas

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe

R's `data.table` package has a really convenient `.GRP` method for generating group index values.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(
  Grp=c("a", "z", "a", "f", "f"),
  Val=c(3, 2, 1, 2, 2)
)
dt[, GrpIdx := .GRP, by=Grp]

   Grp Val GrpIdx
1:   a   3      1
2:   z   2      2
3:   a   1      1
4:   f   2      3
5:   f   2      3
```

What's the best way to accomplish the same thing using `pandas`?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Grp':["a", "z", "a", "f", "f"], 'Val':[3, 2, 1, 2, 2]})
```

Comment: Did you mean `df['GrpIdx'] = df['Grp'].rank(method='dense')` by any chance?

Comment: @NickilMaveli IMHO you should write that as an answer - it's useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.Series.rank.html) to identify unique groups with the `method` arg set to `dense` which accepts `string` values:

```
df['GrpIdx'] = df['Grp'].rank(method='dense').astype(int)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

With Pandas >= 1.1 you can use `groupby.ngroup()`.

In your example:

```
In [39]: df['GrpIdx'] = df.groupby(['Grp']).ngroup()    

In [40]: df                                                                                   
Out[40]: 
  Grp  Val  Grpidx
0   a    3       0
1   z    2       2
2   a    1       0
3   f    2       1
4   f    2       1
```